# Interface for fixed-size container supporting max, min, sum

Tags: c#, interface

I had posted this previously as part of [Generic container similar supporting PeekMax, PeekMin, Sum, and PeekNextToMax](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/93941/generic-container-similar-supporting-peekmax-peekmin-sum-and-peeknexttomax) but I think it was to big a morsel for people to chew on. So I'm splitting it up.

As part of another project (involving portfolio optimization) I'm using an algorithm that requires a data structure supporting the following operations:

- Construct from a `ICollection<T>` or finite `IEnumerable<T>` (The elements are not required to be unique)
- Get the count of elements of the container
- Peek at the container's current maximum (or any of them, if more than one are tied for max) but leave it in the container
- Peek at the container's current minimum (or any of them, if more than one are tied for min) and leave it in the container
- Get the order-2 statistic (any largest element less than or equal to maximum)
- Alter the value of the maximum element ("relaxing")
- Perform an arbitrary operation on all elements of the container except the minimum element (potentially changing them, but no deletions)
- Return the sum (or more generally, an aggregate) of all elements

None of the operations change the number of elements in the container.

The requirements are flexible enough that I don't need the type parameter to implement `IComparable<T>` (although if it does, we can use `IComparer<T>.Default`). If it's not, an ordering function can be passed in to the constructor. The ordering function only needs to determine if one element strictly dominates another -- if they're equal it needs to return `false` -- in other words, it behaves like `>`. Unfortunately I don't see any way to specify this in the interface.

Note that it does *not* require the ability to find or access arbitrary elements, nor does it require the ability to add or remove elements. So it doesn't need to implement `ICollection<T>`.

Here are some questions I'd be interested in reviewers addressing, thouhg of course any comments at all are appreciated:

#### The docstrings

- Are they readable? Am I doing it the right way?
- Do they help make the code understandable?
- Am I missing any XML features I should be using?

#### Other comments

Are they clear? Do they help? Would more of them be helpful? In what places?

#### The interfaces themselves

- Do they clearly and concisely specify what I am looking for?
- Any better ways to do it? (I'm pretty sure there's no way to specify that an interface has to implement an operator, a constructor, or a static method)
- Do the constraints (on the interface itself and on `T`) make sense? Should there be others?

### IAlphaBetaOmega.cs

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="IAlphaBetaOmega.cs" company="Snowbody">
// This file licensed according to the Creative Commons Sharealike License.
// CC-BY-SA
// </copyright>
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Amoeba
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    /// <summary>
    /// Encapsulates a method that has a single parameter and does not return a value.
    /// The method can operate on an element...or change it entirely.
    /// Similar to <see cref="System.Action"/> except it allows reference parameters
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the parameter of the method that this delegate encapsulates.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="obj">The parameter of the method that this delegate encapsulates.</param>
    public delegate void RefAction<T>(ref T obj);

    /// <summary>
    /// Types supporting this interface support adding and subtracting other instances.
    /// Subtraction is the opposite of addition.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of entity that can be added/subtracted</typeparam>
    public interface ISummable<T> where T : new()
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Generalized addition
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="addend">Item to be added</param>
        void Add(T addend);

        /// <summary>
        /// Generalized subtraction, the inverse of <see cref="Plus"/>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sub">Subtrahend (value to be subtracted)</param>
        void Subtract(T sub);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>A collection that supports the operations of returning the most-dominating ("<see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Alpha"/>"),
    /// next-most-dominating ("<see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Beta"/>"), and least-dominating ("<see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Omega"/>") elements,
    /// a sum of all elements ("<see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Sum"/>"),
    /// and supporting the following operations: modify the
    /// most-dominating element, and perform an operation on all of the elements except the least-dominating.</para>
    /// <para>Contracts: After each public operation completes (construction, <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.RelaxAlpha"/>, <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.DoToEachExceptOmega"/>)
    /// no element of the collection dominates <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Alpha"/>,
    /// no element of the collection (except possibly for <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Alpha"/>) dominates <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Beta"/>,
    /// <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Omega"/> does not dominate any element of the collection,
    /// <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Sum"/> is equal to the sum of all elements in the collection
    /// </para></summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of the elements in collection</typeparam>
    public interface IAlphaBetaOmega<T>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the count of items in the collection
        /// </summary>
        int Count { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the most dominating element of the collection
        /// </summary>
        T Alpha { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the next-most dominating element of the collection
        /// </summary>
        T Beta { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the least dominating element of the collection
        /// </summary>
        T Omega { get; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the sum of all elements of the collection
        /// </summary>
        T Sum { get; }

#if false
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new IAlphaBetaOmega&lt;t&gt; by using <param name="comparerFunc" /> to compare elements, with lesser elements dominating.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="collection">The initial values of the collection that we want to scan for alpha, beta, and omega.</param>
        /// <param name="comparerFunc">The System.Collections.Generic.IComparer&lt;T&gt; generic interface implementation to use when comparing elements, or null to use the System.IComparable&lt;T&gt; generic interface implementation of each element.</param>
        /// <returns>A new instance of IAlphaBetaOmega&lt;t&gt; with the specified collection and dominates-rule.</returns>
        public static IAlphaBetaOmega<T> MinAboFactory(IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparerFunc = null);

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new IAlphaBetaOmega&lt;t&gt; by using <param name="comparerFunc" /> to compare elements, with greater elements dominating.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="collection">The initial values of the collection that we want to scan for alpha, beta, and omega.</param>
        /// <param name="comparerFunc">The System.Collections.Generic.IComparer&lt;T&gt; generic interface implementation to use when comparing elements, or null to use the System.IComparable&lt;T&gt; generic interface implementation of each element.</param>
        /// <returns>A new instance of IAlphaBetaOmega&lt;t&gt; with the specified collection and dominates-rule. </returns>
        public static IAlphaBetaOmega<T> MaxAboFactory(IEnumerable<T> collection, IComparer<T> comparerFunc = null);

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new IAlphaBetaOmega&lt;t&gt; by using <param name="dominatesFunc" /> to directly determine whether an element dominates another
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="collection">The initial values of the collection that we want to scan for alpha, beta, and omega.</param>
        /// <param name="dominatesFunc">Function used to determine whether an element dominates another</param>
        /// <returns>A new instance of IAlphaBetaOmega&lt;t&gt; with the specified collection and dominates-rule.</returns>
        public static IAlphaBetaOmega<T> DefaultAboFactory(IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, T, bool> dominatesFunc = null);
#endif
        /// <summary>
        /// Changes the alpha (most-dominating) element of the collection
        /// Note: It's a safe assumption that <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Beta"/> before this runs
        /// will be the same as <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Alpha"/> after this runs
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newValue">The new value of the former alpha element</param>
        void RelaxAlpha(T newValue);

        /// <summary>
        /// Change every element of the collection according to a rule.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="operation">The action to perform</param>
        void DoToEachExceptOmega(RefAction<T> operation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us nitpick a little bit.

There is a little naming issue, which I feel could use some facelifting.

> ```
> public interface ISummable<T> where T : new()
> {
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Generalized addition
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <param name="addend">Item to be added</param>
>     void Add(T addend);
>
>     /// <summary>
>     /// Generalized subtraction, the inverse of <see cref="Plus"/>
>     /// </summary>
>     /// <param name="sub">Subtrahend (value to be subtracted)</param>
>     void Subtract(T sub);
> }
> ```

You have named the parameter for the `Add()` method quite well, but you are using an abbreviation for the parameter of the `Substract()` method.

---

> A collection that supports the operations of returning ...

This does not feel right. It isn't a collection but an interface which defines methods and properties for a collection.

Looking at the object browser for `ICollection<T>` we are seeing the summary:

> Defines methods to manipulate generic collections

Also Microsoft is a little bit to vage, the summary of the `IAlphaBetaOmega<T>` is a little bit overhelming and demanding.

> ```
> /// <para>Contracts: After each public operation completes (construction, <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.RelaxAlpha"/>, <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.DoToEachExceptOmega"/>)
> /// no element of the collection dominates <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Alpha"/>,
> ```

IMHO the summary of an interface should explain how it **should** be implemented. So I would rephrase this and maybe some other parts like so

```
Contracts: After each public operation completes (construction, <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.RelaxAlpha"/>, <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.DoToEachExceptOmega"/>)
no element of the collection should dominate <see cref="IAlphaBetaOmega.Alpha"/>,
```

---

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Change every element of the collection according to a rule.
> /// </summary>
> /// <param name="operation">The action to perform</param>
> void DoToEachExceptOmega(RefAction<T> operation);
> ```

I just don't like this method name. Why not name it e.g `ProcessAlphaBeta()` ?

Comment: You're right, it isn't a collection (it doesn't have to implement `ICollection<T>`. `DoToEachExceptOmega()` is the closest thing to an iterator that an implementation is required to provide. It's more like `System.Array.ForEach()`. so maybe I should rename it to that? Except it specifically avoids calling the operation on the Omega element. The summary there is wrong.